# Button is not responding on Onclick?

Tags: android, facebook, onclicklistener

I have created a button to connect to my FB page through FB App or Browser. Whenever the button is clicked there is no response. I don't know where i did the mistake

So please Guide me ...

```
public class About extends MainActivity implements android.view.View.OnClickListener
{
    Button fb;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.about, null, false);
        mDrawer.addView(contentView, 0);
        fb = (Button) contentView.findViewById(R.id.fb);
        fb.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public static Intent getOpenFacebookIntent(Context context)
    {
        try
        {
            context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0);
            return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("fb://profile/1493553"));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/azaarses"));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (v == fb)
        {
            getOpenFacebookIntent(getApplicationContext());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: check .. fb is null or not  fb.setOnClickListener(this);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This

**Method 1 :**

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (v.getId() == R.id.fb)
    {
        getOpenFacebookIntent(getApplicationContext());
    }
}
```

**Method 2 :**

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.fb:
            getOpenFacebookIntent(getApplicationContext());
        break;

    case R.id.othercases:
            //other cases and their functions.
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Make sure that you have defined `onClickListener()` for `Button`

```
fb = (Button) contentView.findViewById(R.id.fb);
fb.setOnClickListener(this); // defining OnClickListener() for specific `Button`..
```

this may help you..

Comment: Still not Responding :(

Comment: try to put LOG in onClick() method..
if it shows LOG in log-cat then there should be other problem..

Comment: It prints the LOG.I think there is some error in the method

Comment: Good..Now you can use log to check that from which point  your application stops debugging...you can use debug your application to check problem..

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing two object using the assignment operator which will always be false.. instead of comparing two objects try comparing the id of the views.

```
if (v.getId() == R.id.fb)
```

Comment: Still not Responding :(

Comment: Are u sure thAt the on click is not responding??. Try to add log.d on it and check if it prints

Comment: It prints the LOG.I think there is some error in the method

Answer (score 0):

esiest way to do it is with this in your button atributes:

`android:onClick="yourMethodInActivity"`

start by making sure you enter the method with a Log.e at the begining of yourMethodInActivity() for example.

can you print your stack trace?